# how to assign a value to numpy array in specific rows and cols

Tags: python, numpy

i want to assign an array that specific (row, col) with value 1

here is my code:

```
fl = np.zeros((5, 3))
labels = np.random.random_integers(0, 2, (5, 1))
for i in range(5):
    fl[i, labels[i]] = 1
```

is there some shortcut for the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
fl = np.zeros((5, 3))
labels = np.random.random_integers(0, 2, 5)
fl[range(0, 5), labels] = 1
```

And it will produce this output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `labels` array as a boolean array with `fl.shape` as shape. Try:

```
import numpy as np
fl = np.zeros((5, 3))
labels = np.random.random_integers(0, 1, fl.shape).astype(bool)
fl[labels] = 1
```

And here is how the array of boolean's in labels and result will look like:

```
>>> labels
array([[False,  True, False],
   [ True,  True, False],
   [False,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True],
   [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> fl
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
```